# Is correcting 2 consecutive error's in 9 messages from $ GF(2^6) $ by turning tham into 3 messages and solving Reed-Solomon code $ (3, 18) $ possible?

Tags: finite-fields, maple, coding-theory

2 consecutive messages have errors. We have 9 messages from $ GF(2^6, x^6+x+1) $. Messages were encoded with $ (x+1)(x+a)(x+a^2)\sum_{i=1}^6X_ix^{i-1}=\sum_{l=1}^9Y_lx^{l-1} $ , where $ a=(0,0,0,0,1,0) $. I have 9 messages $ \tilde{Y} $ from that $ GF(2^6 $, 2 (consecutive) of which have errors. So I wonder how to solve such problem - get all $ Y $ s corrected?

I wonder if it is possible to turn my 9 items $ \tilde{Y} $ into 3 items $ \tilde{K} $ from some $ GF( 2^{18} ) $ and solve  Reed-Solomon code $ (3, 18) $ following solution described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93196/21249), than turn item from that $ GF( 2^{18} ) $ into 3 items from my  $ GF(2^6) $ and have all my 2 errors corrected? So how to turn from  $ GF(2^6, x^6+x+1) $ into  $ GF(2^{18}, something?) $ and back from that $ GF(2^{18}) $ into my "home" $ GF(2^{6}) $?

Let me introduce an image that explains what I meant by converting 9 messages from $ GF(2^6) $ by turning tham into 3 messages in  $ GF(2^{18}) $.
[image]
My Idea is: if it is any how possible to to turn from  $ GF(2^6, x^6+x+1) $ into  $ GF(2^{18}, something?) $ and back than it is probably possible to turn from  $ GF(2^6, x^6+x+1) $ into  $ GF(2^{24}, something?) $ and back. If we could turn our 9 messages into 3 from $ GF(2^{24}) $ and 3 from $ GF(2^{18}) $  we would always have to fix only one message with error in that field. With simple algorithm, and with out iterations all over blocks.

If such cnversion (from one GF into another, group of messages into message) is possible, than what would be $ a $ in new field, what would be irreducible polynomial for that  $ GF(2^{24}) $ or  $ GF(2^{18}) $ ?

ofcourse we can not bother with $ GF(2^{24}) $ and simply use something like:
[image]

---

So real problem: we have ( as Dilip Sarwate calls them) symbols $ \tilde{Y} $. (in  $ GF(2^6, {\alpha}^{6}+\alpha+1) $)

$$ [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], $$$$[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], $$$$[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], $$$$[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], $$$$[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], $$$$[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], $$$$[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], $$$$[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], $$$$[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] $$

There are $0$ or $1$ or $2$ errors in the 9 symbols. If there are $2$ then they  occur in consecutive positions.

I calculated $ S(\alpha^2) $ , $ S(\alpha) $ and $ S(1) $

$$S(\alpha^2) = \alpha^4+\alpha$$
$$S(\alpha) = \alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^2 $$
$$S(1) = \alpha^4+\alpha^3+1 $$

So  $$ \dfrac{S(\alpha)}{S(1)} = \alpha^5 $$ and $$ \dfrac{S(\alpha^2)}{S(\alpha)} = \alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha $$ and so $ \dfrac{S(\alpha)}{S(1)} $ is $ \neq $ to $ \dfrac{S(\alpha^2)}{S(\alpha)} $ and $$ \dfrac{S(\alpha)}{S(1)} - \dfrac{S(\alpha^2)}{S(\alpha)} = \alpha^4+\alpha$$

I tried to do a brute-force search for solutions to the quadratic equation $$ S(\alpha^2) + [(1+\alpha)S(\alpha)]x + [\alpha S(1)]x^2 = 0 $$ by substituting $ x = 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^8 $ (as Dilip Sarwate sad) and got next results: $$ {\alpha}^{4}+{\alpha}^{3}+{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha+1 $$ $$ {\alpha}^{5}+\alpha $$ $$ {\alpha}^{4}+{\alpha}^{3}+{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha+1 $$ $$ {\alpha}^{5}+{\alpha}^{4}+{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha $$ $$ {\alpha}^{5}+{\alpha}^{2} $$ $$ {\alpha}^{3}+{\alpha}^{2} $$ $$ {\alpha}^{5}+{\alpha}^{3}+{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha+1 $$ $$ {\alpha}^{5}+{\alpha}^{3}+{\alpha}^{2}+\alpha+1 $$ $$ {\alpha}^{5}+{\alpha}^{4}+{\alpha}^{3}+\alpha+1 $$  (Here is [maple file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-HzAcJborshYWI5OTE3YTEtMTFjZi00OGEyLTlmNjItN2RjZWRkMTg1YTcy) I created for playing aroung GF - there is simplified API, tests for it and this task at the end of document...) The book talls me errors shall be located at $6$th and $7$th symbols but I can not find them=(

Comment: Sounds like a *burst error*. Have you searched for more information using that as a keyword? I don't think that remapping this to using a Reed-Solomon code over $GF(2^{18})$ would help. After all, it is possible that the two errorneous 6-bit symbols would straddle the boundary of two 18-bit symbols. More importantly, the resulting code would be different. At least I don't see a way of re-interpreting it that way. Another thing, your terminology sounds a bit non-standard to me. Normally a *single message* is contained in a *codeword*. Here a codeword has 9 *symbols*, each from $GF(64)$.

Comment: Using the notation from my answer to your previous question the system of equations $S(1)=E_1+E_2$, $S(a)=a^{i_0}(E_1+aE_2)$, $S(a^2)=a^{2i_0}(E_1+a^2E_2)$ comes out. Here the symbol $\tilde{Y}_{i_0}$ has an error of size $E_1$ and the symbol $\tilde{Y}_{i_0+1}$ is off by $E_2$. Your code is so short that it is feasible to try the different values of $i_0$, solve for $E_1$ and $E_2$ using the $S(1)$ and $S(a)$-equations, and use $S(a^2)$-equation for verifying that guess was correct/incorrect. IIRC there is a general method, but I don't remember how it goes. Dilip Sarwate may be able to help?

Comment: Something doesn't add up. The first syndrome $S(1)$ is the sum of the received symbols, and I make that 
$$[1,1,1,0,1,0],$$
because the number of 1s per position is $(5,3,3,6,7,4)$ respectively, and here we are only interested in their parity. IOW the syndrome $S(1)$ is either $1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^4$ or $\alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha$ depending on whether your notation is big-endian or little-endian. I cannot check your calculations for the other syndromes, unless you tell which notational convention your SW is following.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the famous review attributed to Dorothy Parker 
"This is not a book to be put down lightly; it should 
be thrown with great force." is fully applicable to
whatever book myWallJSON is using to learn coding theory.
In over forty years in the business, I have never 
encountered such dreadful nonstandard nomenclature 
and notation before!

Be that as it may, borrowing from @JyrkiLahtonen's comment,
the issue here is that if there are $0$ or $1$ or $2$ errors
in the $9$ symbols in a codeword from a $(9,6)$ Reed-Solomon
code over GF$(q)$, then we can guarantee correction of one 
error but *not* two.  *However*,  if the two errors (when they
occur), are guaranteed to be a *burst*, that is, occur 
in consecutive positions, then they can be corrected.  With
$S(1)$, $S(\alpha)$, $S(\alpha^2)$ being the *syndrome*
(evaluations of the received *polynomial* at $1$, $\alpha$,
$\alpha^2$), we proceed as follows.

- If $S(1) = S(\alpha) = S(\alpha^2) = 0$, accept the received
  polynomial as a valid codeword
- If $S(1), S(\alpha) \neq 0$ and 
  $\dfrac{S(\alpha)}{S(1)} = \dfrac{S(\alpha^2)}{S(\alpha)} = \alpha^{i_0}$
  where $0 \leq i_0 \leq 8$, then subtract $S(1)$ from the $i_0$-th received 
  symbol and accept the *corrected* polynomial as a valid codeword.  But if
  $i_0 > 8$, then an uncorrectable error pattern has occurred.  (These 
  assertions might be "off-by-one" because of your nonstandard notation).
- Otherwise, do a brute-force search for solutions to the quadratic
  equation 
  $$S(\alpha^2) + [(1+\alpha)S(\alpha)]x + [\alpha S(1)]x^2 = 0$$
  by substituting $x = 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^8$.

  -- If there
  is a single solution, say $\alpha^4$, then the fourth and fifth symbols
  are in error.  Solve $E_1 + E_2 = S(1), \alpha^4 E_1 + \alpha^5 E_2 = S(\alpha)$ for $E_1$ and $E_2$ to find the error values.
  (These might be "off-by-one" because of your nonstandard notation).

  -- If there are no solutions or there are two solutions, then an undecodable
  error pattern has occurred

  -- There is an elegant solution to quadratic equations over fields of
  characteristic $2$ that avoids brute force search (and no, it does not use
  the usual formula $(-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a$ (can you think why?)) but 
  describing it here will take far too long.

**Edit** Note added in response to a comment by Jyrki Lahtonen

A $(n,k)$ Reed-Solomon code (or more generally a maximum-distance-separable
(MDS) code) over GF$(q)$ has minimum Hamming distance and minimum
Hamming weight $d = n-k+1$.  It also has the property that *any* set of 
$k$ symbol positions (coordinates) can be 
considered to be the information symbols.  Alternatively, given any $d$ 
symbol positions, there are $(q-1)$ codewords (all scalar multiples of
one another) whose $d$ nonzero symbols are in precisely these $d$ positions.

Can an MDS code of minimum distance $d$, $d$ even, correct $\frac{d}{2}$
errors?  No, even though it is true that *most* (but *not all*) received 
words with $\frac{d}{2}$ errors in them are closer to the transmitted 
codeword than to any other codeword.  In fact, most bounded-distance
decoders declare that the error pattern is undecodable in almost all
such cases though serendipitously they do manage to correct 
a few such error patterns.  Are matters any different if we restrict
attention to consecutive errors? 
Can the code correct $\frac{d}{2}$ *consecutive* errors, that
is, all *error bursts* of length $\frac{d}{2}$?  No, but a much
larger fraction of the error bursts of length $\frac{d}{2}$ are
correctable.  Note that there exist codewords whose nonzero symbols 
form two bursts of length $\frac{d}{2}$, and if the error 
pattern is exactly one of these
two bursts, the procedure described above will find both bursts
as possible error patterns, and declare that the pattern is 
undecodable.  Note that *list* decoding, in which the decoder
produces a list of possible transmitted codewords, seems
feasible (but I have not worked out the full details to my
own satisfaction as yet).

Comment: The opening statement alone is worth +1!! I wasn't too sure about the burst-error correcting capability of RS-codes.

Comment: So... for me $ S(1) $  not $ = S(\alpha) $ not $ = S(\alpha^2) $ not $ =0 $ 1) are you sure that  $ \dfrac{S(\alpha)}{S(1)} $ shall be $=$ to $ \dfrac{S(\alpha^2)}{S(\alpha)} $ and $=$ to $ \alpha^{i_0} $? I get $ \alpha^5 $ in  $ \dfrac{S(\alpha)}{S(1)} $  and $ \alpha^5+\alpha^4+\alpha $ on $ \dfrac{S(\alpha^2)}{S(\alpha)} $... 2) I cant get anething out from BruteForce *(all combinations of $ S(\alpha^2) + [(1+\alpha)S(\alpha)]x + [\alpha S(1)]x^2 $ are not NULL =( So what shall I do?

Comment: *(book talls me that errors shall be located at $6$ and $7$th symbols (as you seem to call them) so $\alpha^5$ would seem to be somewhat the thing I shall need... but sadly I do not get $ \alpha^5 $ in    $\dfrac{S(\alpha^2)}{S(\alpha)}$)

Comment: @myWallJSON Please READ the solution carefully. Receiver computes $3$ quantities $S(1),S(\alpha),S(\alpha^2)$. If all are $0$, no errors. **Otherwise** if $S(1),S(\alpha^2)\neq 0$, **and** $S(\alpha)/S(1)=S(\alpha^2)/S(\alpha)$, one error. **If**  $S(\alpha)/S(1)\neq S(\alpha^2)/S(\alpha)$, then **maybe** burst of two errors; decodable if quadratic has unique root. If errors in $6$th and $7$th symbols (detected because $\alpha^5$ is root of quadratic, then **solve** $E_1+E_2=S(1);~E_1\alpha^5+E_2\alpha^6=S(\alpha)$ for $E_1, E_2$. It is not the case here that $S(\alpha^2)/S(\alpha)=\alpha^5$.